# Tengo un problema estoy haciendo un proyecto en mongodb, nodejs y fecht de ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy tratando de traer el nombre del archivo desde la base de datos y a la vez pintarlo, la idea es que me cree un div en el html escriba el nombre de la persona y su descripcion la cual no la guardo en mongodb porque me coloca un limite por lo tanto me vi obligado a guardar en un archivo .txt externo el problema ahora es llamarlo y mostrarlo intente eso y muestra lo mismo el todos los usuarios

```
 fetch(`${ruta}`, { method: 'GET' })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            let html = '';
            data.forEach(archivo => {
              fetch(`/app/user/${archivo.descrip}`)
              .then(result => result.text())
              .then(result => descripcion = result)
                html += `</div><div class="tascontainer"><input type='button' class='subtas' value='Listo'><div class="headertas" ><input type='text' value='${archivo.titulo}' id='${archivo._id}'></div><textarea class="bodytas"  id="/app/teacher/calificar/${archivo._id}a">${descripcion}</textarea></div></div>`;
            });
            vista.innerHTML = html + '<div class="sp-600"></div>';
        }).catch(err => {
            id('mess').setAttribute('class', err.clase);
            id('mess').textContent = err.valor;
            setTimeout(() => {
                id('mess').removeAttribute('class');
                id('mess').textContent = '';
            }, 1000);
        })
```

Comment: Esto: ***el nombre de la persona y su descripcion la cual no la guardo en mongodb porque me coloca un limite*** me llama mucho la atención. ¿Estás diciendo que MongoDB te pone un límite para guardar el nombre de una persona (tal vez 60 caracteres como mucho para un nombre muy largo guardado en un solo campo) y su descripción (imagino que en un campo diferente al de nombre, y quizás 500 a 1000 caracteres si la descripción es poco más que un resumen)? En fin que no entiendo cómo puedes tener problemas para almacenar nombre y descripción en MongoDB. ¿Puedes aclarar? Saludos

Comment: ya solucione el problema. guardaba la descripcion la cual era bastante larga. Asi que la descripcion se guardaba en un archivo generado en formato txt y en mongo se guardaba una referencia a ese archivo. El problema era que necesitaba solicitar todo sobre el usuario y tambien el archivo por lo cual tenia una peticion dentro de otra. 
Lo solucione guardando toda la info de la bd en una variable i luego la iteraba y en cada iteracion hacia pedia el fecth a la referencia del archivo y pintaba todo en pantalla. Si gustas puedo mandar el codigo.

Comment: Entiendo, es razonable pensar que tu campo `descripción` no quepa en un tipo `String` si se trata de texto muy largo. Y por texto largo me refiero a un texto que tenga más de 2^52 caracteres. Aunque no es el límite de un tipo String, si es el límite seguro para que el método `length` te devuelva un valor correcto. Eso, aunado al hecho de que vas a *pintar* dicha descripción en la vista, me siguen haciendo explotar el cerebro sobre el porqué dices que MongoDB te pone un límite. Sin saber exactamente lo que es para ti un valor de *descripción* muy grande, sigo sin entender el problema. Saludos

Comment: Es que mongodb al agregar sierta cantidad de caracteres decia que habia sobre pasado el limite y leí un poco y podia quitar el limite pero bajaba el rendimiento de la base de datos por lo que lo preferi asi